# OpenMP always working on the same thread

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm working with OpenMP and C for a university deliverable and I'm trying to execute the following code, the only thing I wanna do is to see how each section works in every different thread:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {                             
    int id, np;     

    printf("Max threads number: %d\n",omp_get_max_threads());
    omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads());

    #pragma omp parallel sections private(id, np)
    {
        np = omp_get_num_threads(); 
        #pragma omp section
        { 
            id = omp_get_thread_num();
            printf("Hello from thread %d out of %d threads\n", id, np);
        }
        #pragma omp section
        { 
            id = omp_get_thread_num();
            printf("Hello from thread %d out of %d threads\n", id, np);
        }
        #pragma omp section
        { 
            id = omp_get_thread_num();
            printf("Hello from thread %d out of %d threads\n", id, np);
        }
        #pragma omp section
        { 
            id = omp_get_thread_num();
            printf("Hello from thread %d out of %d threads\n", id, np);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm working on Linux, and so when I compile it this say:

```
g++ prueba.c -lgomp -o prueba
```

I'm getting the next output:

```
Max threads number: 4
Hello from thread 0 out of 1 threads
Hello from thread 0 out of 1 threads
Hello from thread 0 out of 1 threads
Hello from thread 0 out of 1 threads
```

Could anyone tell me why it's always working on the thread number 0, and why the omp_get_num_threads() is always 1?

The output I want to achieve is:

```
Max threads number: 4
Hello from thread 0 out of 3 threads
Hello from thread 1 out of 3 threads
Hello from thread 2 out of 3 threads
Hello from thread 3 out of 3 threads
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are missing the `-fopenmp` compiler flag, so the pragmas are ignored. Specify `fopenmp` on all compile and link steps, do not manually link with `-lgomp` unless necessary.

The first statement

```
np = omp_get_max_threads();
```

within a `sections` construct will still be considered a structured block that is only executed by a single thread, as the other answer explains. So your code is equal to:

```
 #pragma omp parallel sections private(id)
 {
     #pragma omp section
     {
         np = omp_get_max_threads();
     }
     #pragma omp section
     { 
     id = omp_get_thread_num();
     printf("Hello from thread %d out of %d threads\n", id, np);
     }
....

Note that you could also split the `parallel` / `sections` and initalize the private variables for each thread:
```

Is just fine. This code is executed by all parallel threads and `np` (with the same value for each thread) is retained through the worksharing `omp section`s. You could even move:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    // Declaring the variables within makes them implicitly private
    // and avoids stupid mistakes
    int np = omp_get_max_threads();
    int id = omp_get_thread_num();
    #pragma omp sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {
            printf("Hello from thread %d out of %d threads\n", id, np);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow... definitely this solved my problem... thank you very much, really!! I appreciate so much the effort of both of you replying to me!

Answer (score 1):

1. By specifying `np` as private, it becomes private to every individual section block. Either copy `np = omp_get_num_threads();` to every individual section (keeping it private) or move it out of the parallel construct completely (removing it from private).
2. section blocks are allowed to run in any sequence, including 4 blocks on the same thread. The output "0, 1, 2, 3" cannot be controlled.

EDIT: to make sure we are on the same line, I copy-paste below the code I tested:

```
 #include <omp.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main() {
 int id, np;

 printf("Max threads number: %d\n",omp_get_max_threads());
 omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads());

 #pragma omp parallel sections private(id)
 {
     np = omp_get_max_threads();
     #pragma omp section
     { 
     id = omp_get_thread_num();
     printf("Hello from thread %d out of %d threads\n", id, np);
     }
     #pragma omp section
     { 
     id = omp_get_thread_num();
     printf("Hello from thread %d out of %d threads\n", id, np);
     }
     #pragma omp section
     { 
     id = omp_get_thread_num();
     printf("Hello from thread %d out of %d threads\n", id, np);
     }
     #pragma omp section
     { 
     id = omp_get_thread_num();
     printf("Hello from thread %d out of %d threads\n", id, np);
     }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your early reply! I tried your both solutions, but I'm still getting the same output as I described for both of them... Anyway, shouldn't omp_get_num_threads() give me the total of threads being in use? So why is it giving me 1, and moreover always working on 0 when I use omp_get_thread_num() ?

Comment: I added the actual code, to be sure. I have no issue with it.

Comment: Aww okay! I missunderstood what u said, I moved np = omp_get_max_threads(); out of the pragma parallel block. Okay so, this way the output gives 4 times:

Hello from thread 0 out of 4 threads

But why the id doesn't change? I want it to work on each thread

Comment: OMG someone posted that I'm missing the -fopenmp flag and that's the solution to my last comment!! But he deleted the post! Thank you very much to both of you!! Thanks to the help of both this is working now!! You're the best guys